# how can we check ionic capacitor share link is success or not

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have tried to solve like I don't have any idea how to check share url is completed or canceled

```
handler: () => {

            Share.share({
              title: 'See cool stuff',
              text: 'Really awesome thing you need to see right meow',
              url: 'http://ionicframework.com/',
              dialogTitle: 'Share with buddies',
            })
            .then((data) => {
              // Success!
              console.log(data)
              const payload = {
                'django_tutorial_subscription': true
              };
              this.authService.user_subscribed(payload, this.user_id).subscribe( data => {
                console.log(data)
              })
             }).catch(() => {
               console.log('done')
             });
            return false;
            
          }
```

Comment: What is a problem? `then()` block - content shared successfully, `catch()` - not. Or what do you want to do?

Comment: Hello Danil  Prokhorenko yes you are right but code is not working in ionic project with capacitor share package.